# Plot the graphs for 2D square lattice for nearest and next nearest neighbours

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am trying to plot the graphs for 2D square lattice for nearest and next nearest neighbours but the plots that I am getting out of it are incorrect.

An N × N matrix is used to represent a 2-D square lattice; every entry of the matrix represents a lattice site and has entry ±1, representing the spin of the particle at that site. A random matrix is initially used so that the initial configuration of spins is randomised.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=15 #  size of the lattice, N x N

init_random = np.random.random((N,N))
lattice_n = np.zeros((N, N))
lattice_n[init_random>=0.75] = 1
lattice_n[init_random<0.75] = -1

init_random = np.random.random((N,N))
lattice_p = np.zeros((N, N))
lattice_p[init_random>=0.25] = 1
lattice_p[init_random<0.25] = -1
```

This is the metropolis algorithm.

A lattice site is selected at random and ∆E is calculated. If ∆E ≤ 0, the change is favourable and the spin is flipped. If `∆E > 0` then the spin is flipped only if `exp (−∆E/kBT) > x` where `x` is a random number on the interval [0, 1] (i.e. the particle has enough energy to flip its spin).
This process is repeated for every site in the lattice, selecting the sites at random.

```
def mcmove(config, beta):
        #Monte Carlo move using Metropolis algorithm 
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                    a = np.random.randint(0, N)
                    b = np.random.randint(0, N)
                    
                    s =  config[a, b] #calling any element of the configuration matrix randomly
                    nb = config[(a+1)%N,b] + config[a,(b+1)%N] + config[(a-1)%N,b] + config[a,(b-1)%N]
                    sb = config[(a+2)%N,b] + config[a,(b+2)%N] + config[(a-2)%N,b] + config[a,(b-2)%N]
                    delta_e = 2*12*s*nb + 2*6*s*sb 
                    if delta_e < 0:
                        s *= -1
                    elif rand() < np.exp(-delta_e*beta):
                        s *= -1
                    config[a, b] = s
        return config
    
    
    def calcEnergy(config):
        #Energy of a given configuration
        energy = 0
        for i in range(len(config)):
            for j in range(len(config)):
                S = config[i,j]
                nb = config[(i+1)%N, j] + config[i,(j+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N, j] + config[i,(j-1)%N]
                sb = config[(i+2)%N, j] + config[i,(j+2)%N] + config[(i-2)%N, j] + config[i,(j-2)%N]
                energy += -nb*S -sb*S
        return energy/4
    
    
    def calcMag(config):
        #Magnetization of a given configuration
        mag = np.sum(config)
        return mag
    
    
    temp_points      = 40         #  number of temperature points
    eqSteps = 300       #  number of MC sweeps for equilibration
    mcSteps = 300      #  number of MC sweeps for calculation
    
    T       = np.linspace(1.53, 3.28, temp_points); 
    E,M,C,X = np.zeros(temp_points), np.zeros(temp_points), np.zeros(temp_points), np.zeros(temp_points)
    n1, n2  = 1.0/(mcSteps*N*N), 1.0/(mcSteps*mcSteps*N*N)
    
    
    
    
    for tp in range(temp_points):
        E1 = M1 = E2 = M2 = 0
        config = lattice_p
        iT=1.0/T[tp]; iT2=iT*iT;
        
        for i in range(eqSteps):         # equilibrate
            mcmove(config, iT)           # Monte Carlo moves
    
        for i in range(mcSteps):
            mcmove(config, iT) #returns the new configuration after monte carlo move          
            Ene = calcEnergy(config)     # calculate the energy
            Mag = calcMag(config)        # calculate the magnetisation
    
            E1 = E1 + Ene
            M1 = M1 + Mag
            M2 = M2 + Mag*Mag 
            E2 = E2 + Ene*Ene
    
        E[tp] = n1*E1
        M[tp] = n1*M1
        C[tp] = (n1*E2 - n2*E1*E1)*iT2
        X[tp] = (n1*M2 - n2*M1*M1)*iT

    f = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10)); # plot the calculated values    
    
    sp =  f.add_subplot(2, 2, 1 );
    plt.scatter(T, E, s=50, marker='o', color='IndianRed')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20);
    plt.ylabel("Energy ", fontsize=20);         plt.axis('tight');
    
    
    
    
    sp =  f.add_subplot(2, 2, 2 );
    plt.scatter(T, abs(M), s=50, marker='o', color='RoyalBlue')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20); 
    plt.ylabel("Magnetization ", fontsize=20);   plt.axis('tight');
    
    sp =  f.add_subplot(2, 2, 3 );
    plt.scatter(T, C, s=50, marker='o', color='IndianRed')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20);  
    plt.ylabel("Specific Heat ", fontsize=20);   plt.axis('tight');   
    
    sp =  f.add_subplot(2, 2, 4 );
    plt.scatter(T, X, s=50, marker='o', color='RoyalBlue')
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (T)", fontsize=20); 
    plt.ylabel("Susceptibility", fontsize=20);   plt.axis('tight');
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: "The plots are incorrect" is a bit vague.  Can you explain clearly the expected output?

Comment: specific heat and susceptibility was supposed to show  discontinuity.  Magnetisation was supposed to drop with increasing temperature

Comment: suppose i consider only for the nearest neighbouring lattice                                                                                                       ''' nb = config[(a+1)%N,b] + config[a,(b+1)%N] + config[(a-1)%N,b] + config[a,(b-1)%N]                                 '''    if we consider 2*J1*s*nb                                                                                          in this case, while computing for lower values of J1 for example, J1=1 (above i have assumed J1 = 12 and J2 = 6) , I am getting the expected results